# ASP.Net HyperLink's NavigateUrl changes after rendering in to HTML Anchor

Tags: asp.net, html, hyperlink, anchor, navigateurl

I am quite new to ASP.Net. I have a Master.aspx and a Page1.aspx and Page2.aspx, all in the same directory.

Master:

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="Page1.aspx" runat="server" Text="Page 1" />
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="Page2.aspx" runat="server" Text="Page 2" />
```

both the Page1 and Page2 gets rendered from above master page.

all three are in a vertual directory which is mapped as a subdomain here are the details:

Virtual Drectory: dirvir
Domain: dirvir.example.com

now when I open any of the page say:

```
http://dirvir.example.com/Page1.aspx
```

the Hyperlinks are rendered containing

```
href="../virdir/Page1.aspx"
href="../virdir/Page2.aspx"
```

respectively.

On click of them it takes me to

```
http://dirvir.example.com/dirvir/Page1.aspx
http://dirvir.example.com/dirvir/Page2.aspx
```

where as I wanted it to be

```
http://dirvir.example.com/Page1.aspx
http://dirvir.example.com/Page2.aspx
```

I can achive the same by using <a> but i need them on the code behind too so thats not desired.

> Note: using <a> with runat server also
>   behaves in the same way HyperLink
>   does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this as indicated below change the NavigateUrl,

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/Page1.aspx" runat="server" Text="Page 1" />
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/Page2.aspx" runat="server" Text="Page 2" />
```

Or

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="/Page1.aspx" runat="server" Text="Page 1" />
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="/Page2.aspx" runat="server" Text="Page 2" />
```

Comment: it works only when the pages and master page are directly in the virtual directory, but what if they are in a folder in that virtual directory the link tries to get it from virual directory e.g. `http://dirvir.example.com/testdir/Page1.aspx` will be having urls containing `http://dirvir.example.com/Page1.aspx`

Comment: did you surely tried the second suggesion ,<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="/Page1.aspx" runat="server" Text="Page 1" /> 
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="/Page2.aspx" runat="server" Text="Page 2" /> this surely should work i just tested this with child virtual directories setup

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio click on the Project Name in the Solution Explorer. Once you do this, you will find a property under the properties window called `Virtual Path`, which will have the value `/dirvir`. Change this to `/`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it to be a server-side link, just use a regular anchor tag and let ASP.NET figure out the correct path based on your virtual directory for your web application:

```
<a href="<%: ResolveURL("~/Page1.aspx")%>">Page 1</a>
```

Comment: thats the problem I want them on the server-side and also I want to STOP ASP.net to think about my URLs. let it be there as it is